# Refused to execute script admin-ajax.php in WordPress plugin due to MIME type ('text/html') is not executable

Tags: jquery, ajax, wordpress

I'm editing a popup plugin based on Pippity popups and it does the following code when opening the popup. The results in most browsers except FF is the error "Refused to execute script from 'http://demo.goldhat.ca/wanderbaum/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=Wand_getAc…ax=true&ref=&href=demo.goldhat.ca/wanderbaum/hello-world/&url=Wand_open_18' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled."

I think the reason a script element is created with the return from admin-ajax.php is because it contains a mix of JSON and javascript functions. My understanding is limited in this but I suspect if we did a jQuery ajax call the return would not run as JS, but with this approach the return is treated like a JS file so the functions can still run. However the mime type is text/html, not the expected mimetype for a JS file.

Is there a solution without having to completely change how this is structured? Is there a way to force a mimetype (in the code) without changing the server (it needs to run on multiple servers as a WP plugin).

```
var href = location.href.replace(location.hash, '').replace('http://', '').replace('https://', '');
var ref = document.referrer.replace('http://', '').replace('https://', '');
var hash = location.hash.substr(1).length ? location.hash.substr(1) : 'empty'; 
var url = WAND_AJAX+'?action=Wand_getActive&incoming_ajax=true&ref='+ref+'&href='+href+'&url='+location.hash.substr(1)+loadPops;

var s = document.createElement('script');
s.id = 'Wand_w';
s.src = url;
s.text = 'text/javascript';
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(s);
```

Comment: WAND_AJAX is the base url for the WP site like http://demo.goldhat.ca/wanderbaum/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php

Comment: To clarify the ajax return from admin-ajax.php needs to be "executable javascript", which (I suspect) is why a script tag is appended using appendChild.